# Cloudformation AllowedPattern - Can't figure out the format

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to deploy an appliance from the AWS Marketplace and one of the configuration options the template is asking for is a

"Trusted Network CIDR (required)
Allow all traffic (including TCP port 22 and 4444) from this CIDR on the public network interface."

The template looks like this:

```
PublicNetworkCIDR:
    Description: Allow all TCP traffic (except port 22 and 4444) from this CIDR on the public network interface.
    Type: String
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    AllowedPattern: ^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))$
    ConstraintDescription: 'Must be IPv4 CIDR notation: X.X.X.X/X'
```

No matter what I've tried, I can't get it to accept anything.  What is it looking for??

I've tried 98.1.1.1/32, 255.255.255.0, 255.255.255.255/32, 172.30.30.0/24

Answer (score 0):

The valid `AllowedPattern` for a CIDR range [is](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/master/aws/services/VPC/VPC_EC2_Instance_With_Multiple_Static_IPAddresses.yaml#L40):

```
(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})
```

Comment: So is there something I can do that will match this pattern, then once the Security Group is built I'll just change it?  What will match it?

Comment: @kawami1910 Not sure what do you mean.

Comment: What pattern will match:
^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))$

Comment: @kawami1910 Don't know. It does not work anyway as you stated.